# Como faço para alterar apenas um campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Quando altero um dado de uma tabela, altera todos os outros campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo :

```
<?php

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$nome_produto = isset($_POST['nome_produto']) ? $_POST['nome_produto'] : '';
$quantidade = isset($_POST['quantidade']) ? $_POST['quantidade'] : '';
$valor_produto = isset($_POST['valor_produto']) ? $_POST['valor_produto'] : '';


include_once("conexao.php");

$sql = "UPDATE produto SET nome_produto = '$nome_produto', quantidade = '$quantidade' , valor_produto='$valor_produto' ";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (!$res) {
    die('Erro ao alterar o produto ' . mysql_error());

    } else {

    if($res) {
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Produto alterado com sucesso!');window.location.href='estoque.php'</script>";

    } else {

    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Nao foi possivel alterar esse produto, tente novamente');window.location.href='alterar.php'</script>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Não da pra entender muito bem sua pergunta, poderia reformular ? Formate sua tabela e mostre o que você deseja alterar, e adicione os códigos com o campo específico para eles.
De uma lida aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?cb=1

Comment: O é porque você esta fazendo um UPDATE sem where.

Comment: Se eu coloco o Where , ele da a mensagem de sucesso e não altera as informações ...

Comment: Você deve receber o id do produto a ser alterado através do formulario, para só então usar a clausula where. Exemplo: `$id_produto = isset($_POST['id_produto']) ? $_POST['id_produto'] : '';` e na consulta `"UPDATE ... valor_produto='$valor_produto' WHERE id_produto = $id_produto "`